# how can I apply for loop through more than one pages and add each page to csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping

how can I get more data form more than one  page into my csv file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
source = requests.get('https://software-overzicht.nl/amersfoort?page=1','https://software-overzicht.nl/amersfoort?page=2' ).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv','w')
csv_writter = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writter.writerow(['naambedrijf', 'adress'])
for search in soup.find_all('div', class_='company-info-top'):
    title = search.a.text
    adress = search.p.text
    for page in range(1, 22):
        url = 'https://software-overzicht.nl/amersfoort?page={}'.format(page)
    print(title)
    csv_writter.writerow([title,adress])
csv_file.close()`
```

Comment: Implement a loop over the URLs. Open the CSV file before the outer loop. Close the csv file after the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your `requests.get()` and that whole process into your loop of the page range:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('C:/cms_scrape.csv','w', newline='') as f:
    csv_writter = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writter.writerow(['naambedrijf', 'adress'])

    for page in range(1, 22):
        url = 'https://software-overzicht.nl/amersfoort?page={}'.format(page)
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        for search in soup.find_all('div', class_='company-info-top'):
            title = search.a.text.strip()
            adress = search.p.text.strip()

            print(title)
            csv_writter.writerow([title,adress])
```